# selenium webdriver code to click on 'Album' in facebook

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click on 'Albums' in Facebook.
The HTML is Albums how to locate the element 'Albums' in selenium web driver.

I tried with using `driver.findelement(By.xpath(span[@class="_3sz"])` showing error as element not found

And, the html looks the following:

```
<span class="_3sz">Albums</span>
```

Comment: I tried with using driver.findelement(By.xpath(span[@class="_3sz"]) showing error as element not found

Comment: How does the html looks like?

Comment: the html is <span class="_3sz">Albums</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your problem correctly then that xpath you mentioned returns more than one elements. Use a text based search which is more easier and specific.

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[.='Albums']").click();
```

And, here `.` is used to directly point to the parent element. Additional wait might be needed to wait for the element to interact. Also, I am assuming you are trying to click the element.

**EDIT**

```
 Driver = new ChromeDriver();
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

 Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
 Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
 Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#email")).SendKeys("your email");
 Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#pass")).SendKeys("your pass");
 Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[type='submit'][value='Log In']")).Click();
 Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".fbxWelcomeBoxName")).Click();
 Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[.='Photos']")).Click();
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[.='Albums']")));
 Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[.='Albums']")).Click();
 By albumname = By.XPath("//strong[.='2014']"); //this should be your album name. In my case it's 2014
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(albumname));
 Driver.FindElement(albumname).Click();
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector(".fbPhotoAlbumHeader.fbPhotoAlbumOptionsPresent [type='file']")));
 Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".fbPhotoAlbumHeader.fbPhotoAlbumOptionsPresent [type='file']")).SendKeys(@"D:\Users\Saifur\Desktop\FacebookPicture\150232_585410621540701_1836495431_a.jpg");
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector(".pvm.phl.footerBox.uiBoxWhite")));
 Driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("[name='postPhotosButton']")));
 Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[name='postPhotosButton']")).Click();
```

*Notice mine is C#*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67277/discussion-on-answer-by-saifur-selenium-webdriver-code-to-click-on-album-in-fa).

Comment: See my code I added. Not the best way but good for a started to understand

Comment: Hi thank You so much. will try this. Can you please do one more help i want to click on compose in gmail which has html <div class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3" tabindex="0" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" gh="cm">COMPOSE</div> i tried with xpath By.xpath("//*[.='COMPOSE']") I tried with classname also but its showing error as eleent not found

Comment: Try this `//*[.='COMPOSE'][@role='button']`

Comment: Please post a different question if not related to this thread. I don't want to extend the discussion here and they will lock my account and would highly appreciate if the facebook answer is accepted

Answer (score 0):

It always best practice to follow this sequence while selecting elements.

1) ID

2) CSS

3) XPath (This will have some issues with different browsers specially IE)

In this case, considering this is no other span class with same name. It would have work like this "span._3sz". Simple and powerful.